# Audio Noise Filter

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working on 1 (one) human voice detection application, but i need help to remove noise (low pass filter) from audio file which is already recorded or during record.

I'm recording audio in `.caf` format, after that converting that file to `.mp3` to noise removal.

Please help if any body have solution,i'm stuck there.

Comment: Can we see your Minimal, concise code?

Comment: Better **hope** that your noise is actually in the high frequencies, because that's not guaranteed in any way. Also, that sentence about `.mp3` makes no sense gramatically.

Comment: Audio is recording in .caf format after recording i'm converting .caf file to .mp3 file to remove noise. Because noise can not be removed from .caf file that's y i have converting in .mp3 audio file